# How to play rtsp live streaming in android lower devices?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, android-videoview

I want to play the video from live streaming as rtsp.Below is the code i am using to play the video

```
    try {

        String http_url="rtsp://live.wmncdn.net/jiljillive/bbb19eae240ec100af921d511efc86a0.sdp";
        //String link = "http://qn.vc/files/data/2947/The%20Pappi%20-%20Heropanti%20-%20Feat%20Raftaar%20%5BMobMp4.Com%5D.mp4.mp4";
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(http_url);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This code works fine in Android 4.x mobile devices.But it gives the error message as sorry cant play the video in Android 2.x mobiles

Please give me the solution for playing live video RTSP streaming in Android lower devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you are right.

RTSP is support from 2.x but , sdp format is not supported by older android versions.

**So what is the possible ways to support this?**

1. If you have rights to access and modify **RTSP** server you can
   implement **FFMPEG** library that will convert the **sdp** format to **mp3**
   which is widely accepted and also work with android 2.x devices.
2. If **RTSP** server is of third party and you do not have rights to
   modify it, you cant use **FFMPEG** library in you android project. But
   to use that you need to have enough knowledge of **Android NDK**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
videoView.setVideoPath(http_url);
videoView.requestFocus();
```

And at the `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)` method use:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
}
```